# Listing all EPSG projections to serve it on the client side

Tags: python, gdal, epsg, value-list, flask

I am building a web app that allows user to convert and reproject their spatial data and then download it. I am using Flask and ogr2ogr to achieve this.

Now, I want to give users a list of EPSG projections so they can choose to transform data to desired projection. I was thinking to populate select element in the in the HTML page using JavaScript, so they can choose and then take input value to ogr2ogr function on the back-end.

How can I get all available projection and serve it to user?

Comment: PostGIS should list this and/or a google search should find these fairly quickly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PostGIS Spatial Reference Systems table can be found here:

https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/spatial_ref_sys.sql?raw=true

Source on GitHub: https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/spatial_ref_sys.sql

Perhaps you can parse that out and/or use SQL to convert it to JSON.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked. I used `select auth_name, srid from spatial_ref_sys` and then converted it to JSON.

Comment: @DrJacoby Excellent!

Comment: @DrJacoby Feel free to post the corresponsing JSON to pastebin, for example. It could be useful for many applications.

Comment: It's a good suggestion @Eric Duminil. I posted  file to **pastebin**. You can see it at:https://pastebin.com/EkstsWu7. Maybe I should later add some other attributes like description of the projection.

Comment: @DrJacoby: Thanks, it's a good start. Right now, it could be just a list of integers, since it doesn't contain any more information. If you want a list of dictionaries, name and proj4 parameters would be great.

Answer (score 9):

GDAL is using Proj and Proj since version 6 keeps the definitions or coordinate reference systems in a small SQLite database that is named "proj.db". Therefore the most natural place for building your list is to query them from the proj.db database. PostGIS in not a bad alternative because spatial_ref_sys is filled with data from proj.

Python can be used for making SQL queries from SQLite but I attach couple of screenshots from DB Browser for SQLite for showing what kind of structure the proj.db has. The tables that are needed are `"geodetic_crs"` and `"projected_crs"` and from those fields `"auth_name"`, `"code"`, and perhaps `"name"`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I am now considering to implement this approach. Can you explain me how to include proj.db to python code? Do I need to import some environment variables? Can you tell me where can I find proj.db from file explorer? I am using Linux mint.

Comment: I do not quite understand the issue https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/1490 that deals with finding proj.db automatically. However, if PROJ_LIB is set that should point to right directory.